# How can I make two dimensional array with JSON objects into single array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

Here i have a JSON object in an array and have it pushed to employeeArray which is

```
employeeArray =[  
  [  
    {  
      "ID":"967",
      "NAME":"Dang, Lance D",
      "Email":"Lance.Dang@xyz.com"
    }
  ],
  [  
    {  
      "ID":"450",
      "NAME":"Starnes, Mitch",
      "Email":"Mitchell.Starnes@xyz.com"
    }
  ],
  [  
    {  
      "ID":"499",
      "NAME":"Cosby, Lance H",
      "Email":"Lance.Cosby@xyz.com"
    }
  ]
];
```

How do i get this into a single array with JSON objects like this

```
employeeArray =[  
  {  
    "ID":"967",
    "NAME":"Dang, Lance D",
    "Email":"Lance.Dang@xyz.com"
  },
  {  
    "ID":"450",
    "NAME":"Starnes, Mitch",
    "Email":"Mitchell.Starnes@xyz.com"
  },
  {  
    "ID":"499",
    "NAME":"Cosby, Lance H",
    "Email":"Lance.Cosby@xyz.com"
  }
];
```

help me how to use above two dimensional array values and build my expected array in pure javascript

Comment: Start by *learning*, for example, try googling "what is json" & "javascript array". Then think about what got you into this state you're trying to get out of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to flatten the array, which can be done with a [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) call:

```
employeeArray.reduce((p, c) => p.concat(c), [])
```

ES5:

```
employeeArray.reduce(function (p, c) {
  return p.concat(c);
}, []);
```