# What is the difference between these two JSON object sets?

Tags: angularjs, json

I have difficulty understanding between this type of JSON objects. They work differently in my code.

What is the difference between this:
(A)

```
[
    [
        { department: 'A', name: 'santos' },
        { department: 'B', name: 'suarez' },
        { department: 'C', name: 'domingo' },
        { department: 'A', name: 'james' },
        { department: 'B', name: 'black' }
    ]
];
```

And this:
(B)

```
[
    { department: 'A', name: 'santos' },
    { department: 'B', name: 'suarez' },
    { department: 'C', name: 'domingo' },
    { department: 'A', name: 'james' },
    { department: 'B', name: 'black' }
];
```

Aside from the extra brackets on each sides.

I have to put `JSON.stringify(value)` just to read the one in set (A). and I get this extra elements

```
"$$hashKey":"object:23"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the $$hashKey added to my JSON.stringify result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826320/what-is-the-hashkey-added-to-my-json-stringify-result)

Comment: [there is no such thing as JSON objects](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). Apart from the "extra brackets", those JS objects seem exactly the same (unless there are hidden characters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A- Is  a  multi-dimensional

B - Is a two dimensional array

Go to this if you want [Convert object to multi-dimensional array - JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43690246/convert-object-to-multi-dimensional-array-javascript)

Go to this if you want [How can I make two dimensional array with JSON objects into single array in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34751702/how-can-i-make-two-dimensional-array-with-json-objects-into-single-array-in-java)

And kindly take a look for this [What is JSON and why would I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383692/what-is-json-and-why-would-i-use-it)